# Converting followPath(_:asOffset:orientToPath:speed:) to iOS 7.1 compatible version in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

In SpriteKit is there an equivalent to the SpriteKit SKAction of followPath(*:asOffset:orientToPath:speed:)?? If there is not can I use the followPath(*:asOffset:orientToPath:duration:) method instead and calculate the duration to speed?? I am trying to have a SKSpriteNode follow a CGPath. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

followPath(:asOffset:orientToPath:duration:) is available since iOS7.0, so you definitel can use that method